# `Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.accountType` misreporting office account types

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

We have an Outlook add-in that has a feature that is only enabled for users whose mailboxes are provided by a Microsoft 365 subscription. A small number of users (all of whom are using the PC desktop version of Outlook) have recently reported that this feature has been disabled despite previously working and they definitely do have Microsoft 365 accounts, which we have verified using https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/O365ExchangeDns/input.

We get the user’s account type from Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.accountType, and in the cases mentioned above, it is being misreported as `enterprise` when it should be `office365`.

Have there been any recent changes or issues that would affect the reported account type of desktop Outlook users on PC? Has anyone else encountered a similar issue, and if so has anyone found a fix? In some cases our users have been able to resolve this by either restarting or updating Outlook, but in at least one case this has not resolved the issue.

Comment: This information is usually stored in the Outlook Profile. You could try recreating the profile with the same account, to see if it fixes it.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-outlook-profile-f544c1ba-3352-4b3b-be0b-8d42a540459d?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#:~:text=1%20In%20Outlook%2C%20select%20File%20%3E%20Account%20Settings,profile%2C%20and%20then%20choose%20OK%20.%20See%20More